# Google App Engine is not picking up Log4j

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, log4j, appender

Google App Engine does not create a file when using the file appender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine simply does not provide access to the file system. You [can read](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java?hl=en#readfile) from within your web-application, but you [can't write](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java?hl=en#writefile) anywhere. Those restrictions are the same for any framework you are using.

Most common example: you can upload file only with [File Streaming API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html), without storing actual file in some temporary folder.